# Multiple models and Paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord, paperclip

I was wondering if it is possible to have multiple models all using one central model for its images using paperclip.. So for example I would have a photo model which would use paperclip to store its urls etc

In my case I have 2 models, portfolio and post, both of which have a form which allow you to upload images and other attributes to the model.

So can both models have a

```
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

or would i need to create separate models for each of the photos, ie photo1, photo2 to do this? so that the portfolio model feeds off one and post model feeds off another for its images?

I am just looking to get a better understanding and keep things DRY

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polymorphic associations, where more then one model will have many photos.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised

**example:**

Your model will be called media and will belong to mediable, where mediable might be article, user, post, etc..:

`belongs_to :mediable, ploymorphic: true`

User, Article, Post model or another:

`has_many :medias, as: mediable`

Comment: thanks for the answer, can i ask another question then please... if i name my model to store all images MEDIA, then any time i want another model to be able to use this model i do has_many :medias, as: mediable as you have stated?

Comment: ok so what if my model was called Photo? its the medias -> mediable transition im not sure about... is there a particular naming convention? would photo become photoable ?

Comment: well.. in a project we worked on we used mediable as it sounds better, calling your association as photoable sounds weird, but I guess you can use it too if it doesn't bother you. The point is to set this ending "able" at the end, like: commentable, mediable, postable, etc.. at least this is the way I understood it works.

Comment: Although I think other wordings will work to, like in your case with photo model, `belongs_to :mediable, polymorphic: true` and for related models, `has_many :photos, as: :mediable`. This should work too but never tried as I didn't had this cases yet.

Comment: yes that makes sense, dont want to confuse matters :) thanks for explaining